# Getting the message from defined in a Django RegexValidator object

Tags: django, django-validation

I defined a RegexValidator using Django's built-in class. Like as follows:

```
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

validate_alphanumeric = RegexValidator(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$', 'Only alphanumeric characters are allowed.')
```

The issue is that I am using this from outside of the model definition. Like as follows:

```
try:
    validate_alphanumeric("++")
except:
    # Somehow get the message defined above, that is get 'Only alphanumeric characters are allowed.'
```

In other words, if the string passed causes an error, I want to get the message stored in my RegexValidator object definition. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catch the exception and use the `message` attribute of the validation error.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

try:
    validate_alphanumeric("++")
except ValidationError as exc:
    message = exc.message
```